# how can linked between component in to the card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I want to link the card button with another component that I already have, but I don't know how to do it, could you help me?

Here I show you the card component, where in the Card.Footer label I want to put the link to the roles component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';
import AllRoles from './Roles';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

const baseURL = "../cartas.json";

const Cards = () => {
    const [carta, setCarta] = useState([])

    //FORMA CON AXIOS
    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`${baseURL}`)
            .then((response) => {
                setCarta(response.data.cita);
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log(err.message) });
    }, []);
    console.log(carta);

    const renderCard = (card, index) => {
        if (carta.length) {
            return (
                // <Routes>
                <Card className=" col-1 col-md-3 w-15 mx-auto" key={index} >
                    <Card.Img src={card.imagen}
                        alt={card.nombre}
                        className="py-3 px-3 mx-auto"
                        style={{ width: "12rem" }}>
                    </Card.Img>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <p className="card-title">{card.descripcion}</p>
                    </Card.Body>
                    <Card.Footer className=" fs-3 py-3 px-3">
                        {/* <Link to="roles">Roles</Link> */}
                        {/* <NavLink to={card.link}>Roles</NavLink> */}
                        {/* <Routes>
                            <Route path={card.link}>
                                <Roles/>
                            </Route>

                            </Routes> */}
                        {/* <BrowserRouter>
                           
                        </BrowserRouter> */}
                    </Card.Footer>

                    {/* <Route exact path="/roles" component={AllRoles}></Route> */}
                </Card>
                // </Routes>

            )
        }
        //     )
        // }
    }
    return (
            <div className='app row row-cols-12 gap-5 justify-content-md-center'>
                {carta.map(renderCard)}
            </div>
    )
}
export default Cards;
```

As you can see I have tried with the routes but without success, I have commented it because when I put it everything disappears

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ditto";

const AllRoles = () => {
    const [roles, setRol] = useState([]);

    ///FORMA CON FETCH 
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${baseURL}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return response.json();
            })
            
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                // setCarta(data.cita);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message)
            });
    }, []);
console.log("hola");
  
}

export default AllRoles;
```

Then here I have the roles component, which I want that when clicking on the card, the information will appear on the console for now